# Is there a better solution for formatting serial?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this piece of code. What I want to know is if there is a more elegant solution for this.

```
  /**
   * Formats serial from '86FC64484BE99E78' to '86:FC:64:48:4B:E9:9E:78'
   * @param serial
   */
  private formatSerial(serial: string): string {
    return serial.split('').reduce(
      (prev, curr, index, arr) => {
        let part = prev + curr;
        if ((index % 2 === 1) && (index !== arr.length - 1)) {
          part += ':';
        }
        return part;
      },
      '',
    );
  }
```

Comment: `function splitby($text){    return $text.match(/.{1,2}/g).join(':'); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code or check live demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zcb8kw

```
private formatSerial(serial: string): string {
  return serial.match(/.{1,2}/g).join(':')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following  solution:

```
  formatSerial($serial){
      return $serial.match(/.{1,2}/g).join(':');
  }
```